# powershell get-qadcomputer + wmi query

Tags: powershell, wmi, quest

Please can someone tell me how to use

```
***Get-QADComputer -LdapFilter "(operatingsystem=*server*)"***
```

in my script below. (I can get it to work with the text file it just fails on the get-qadcomputer bit)

```
***function inventory {
PROCESS {
$os = gwmi win32_operatingsystem -comp $_
$cs = gwmi win32_computersystem -comp $_
$obj = new-object psobject
$obj | add-member noteproperty Name $os.csname
$obj | add-member noteproperty RebootDate $os.ConvertToDateTime($os.LastBootUpTime)
$obj | add-member noteproperty Manufacturer $cs.manufacturer
$obj | add-member noteproperty Model $cs.model
$obj | add-member noteproperty Operating_System $os.caption
$obj | add-member noteproperty Architecture $os.OSArchitecture
$obj | add-member noteproperty Service_Pack $os.ServicePackMajorVersion
write-output $obj
}
}
gc C:\scripts\lastreboot\syn_pc.txt -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | inventory | Export-Csv c:\scripts\lastreboot\inventory2.csv***
```

Comment: I think the main reason Get-QADComputer isn't working in the code you posted is that you don't have Get-QADComputer in the code.

Comment: sorry perhaps i wasn't clear when i replace gc C:\scripts\lastreboot\syn_pc.txt -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue with the first bit I put it fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue you're facing is that the **inventory** function you wrote was designed to use $_ directly, and you are assuming that the $_ Variable will only be a string.  The command works initially because you are extracting a list of names from a file, which is giving you a list of names which are of type **[String]**, and passing this collection/list of strings into the pipeline for **inventory** to use.

But when using Get-QADComputer, you are getting objects of type **[Selected.Quest.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShellSnapIn.Data.ArsComputerObject]** which is so much more then just a list of names.  The objects have a name property, which i assume you truly are after, along with other information.  You need to pull just the name portion out and pass that along into the pipeline

So you have two options:

- Change the inventory function to account for the difference in input types from the pipeline (simple strings which contain the just names, or objects that have a name property and use just the name portion)
- Change the way in which you are calling the script

Here is the command, I think you want

```
 Get-QADComputer -LdapFilter "(operatingsystem=*server*)" | Select -ExpandProperty Name | inventory | Export-Csv c:\scripts\lastreboot\inventory2.csv
```

Note the **Select -ExpandProperty Name**, which takes the ADObject and will pass only the name along into the pipeline which your inventory function is expecting

Comment: Thanks for your help it works a dream! I had tried the "select Name" bit previously, didn't realise I had got so close. Many thanks for your detailed explanation.

Comment: Glad i could help.   The real trick of it, is understanding that you need -ExpandProperty and not just Select Name.  Select Name would still give you the original object, but with just the selected properties (Property and value).   Select -ExpandProperty Name strips away the object and gives you the values ONLY.